# ORA-00932 Несовместимые типы данных: ожидается -, получено CLOB. Ошибка при использовании PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot, clob

)
Прошу руку помощи, облазал весь интернет, не нашел решения для моей проблемы..
Написал такой запрос:

Select *

from
(
Select

```
  q.POLYGON_ID

 ,q.GEO_WKT

 ,q.SRC_SRC_ID

 ,POLYGON_ATTR_KEY

 ,POLYGON_ATTR_VALUE

 ,w.NAVI_DATE

 ,w.SNAP_DATE
```

from DWX.S_GEO_POLYGONS q

join DWX.S_GEO_POLYGON_ATTR w

on q.polygon_id = w.polygon_id

)

pivot ( max (POLYGON_ATTR_VALUE)
for POLYGON_ATTR_KEY in ('CENTER_BMT' as CENTER_BMT,
'ID_BRANCH' as ID_BRANCH,
'NAME_BRANCH' as NAME_BRANCH,
'NAME_SUBJECT' as NAME_SUBJECT,
'ID_SUBJECT' as ID_SUBJECT,
'COMMENT_STR' as COMMENT_STR,
'TYPE_BMT' as TYPE_BMT,
'NAME_BMT' as NAME_BMT,
'POPULATION_BMT' as POPULATION_BMT,
'Y' as lat,
'X' as lon)
)

Атрибут q.GEO_WKT является типа CLOB  и содержит координаты. Если закоментить данный атрибут, все работает правильно. С ним выдает ошибку: ORA-00932 Несовместимые типы данных: ожидается -, получено CLOB
Как побороть данную проблему не понимаю.. Прошу помочь по возможности.
Заранее большущие спасибо!

Comment: Пробовал так, тоже ерунда получается..
to_char(q.GEO_WKT)
Пишет: Размер буфера не достаточен для преобразования CLOB в CHAR (Фактически 47890: максимум: 4000)

Comment: Удалось решить вопрос выносом селекта атрибута clob в отдельный селект.